# How to provide custom name resolution in Docker containers

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, virtualhost

Assume I have the following file structure

```
.                                  
├── docker-compose.yml             
└── webserver                      
    ├── Dockerfile                 
    ├── html                       
    │   ├── test1                  
    │   │   └── index.html         
    │   └── test2                  
    │       └── index.html         
    └── vhosts.conf                

4 directories, 5 files
```

with `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    webserver:
        build: webserver
        container_name: web
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - ./webserver/html/:/application
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    other:
        image: php:7.2.7
        container_name: other
        tty: true
```

with `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.2.7-apache

COPY vhosts.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

with `vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test1.localhost

    DocumentRoot /application/test1
    <Directory /application/test1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test2.localhost

    DocumentRoot /application/test2
    <Directory /application/test2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and the `index.html` files just with some content to distinguish them.

Additionally, I added the following lines to my **docker host's** `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   test1.localhost
127.0.0.1   test2.localhost
```

Now I can run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` to setup and run the containers. When running `curl test1.localhost` on either the host machine or the `web` container I get the expected content of the `index.html`. However, if I run the same command from the `other` container I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to test1.localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

I found at https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/ the following quote:

> In the absence of the --dns=IP_ADDRESS..., --dns-search=DOMAIN..., or --dns-opt=OPTION... options, Docker uses the /etc/resolv.conf of the host machine (where the docker daemon runs).

So to my understanding the name resolution inside the containers simply uses the entries from the hosts file of the docker host. However, this fails on the `other` container because the `/etc/hosts` file resolves the names to `127.0.0.1` but the `other` container is not running a webserver. I want the names on `other` to be revolved to the `web` container.

This is obviously a minimal example. I need this kind of behaviour for a dev setup of a web app where I want to run cronjobs from a container separate from the one where the apache host is running. The scripts run by the cronjobs perform http requests to different hosts in the container.

I suspect the solution to somehow use the docker networks configuration...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, with some help of the Docker Slack channel I found a solution, actually even two to be precise...

## Using Docker Network aliases

First solution uses [docker network aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases). Essentially I explicitly spelled out the default network both containers belong to and created some aliases for the webserver container.

`docker-compose-yml`:

```
version: "3.1"

services:

    webserver:
        build: webserver
        container_name: web
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - ./webserver/html/:/application
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        networks:
            default:
                aliases:
                    - test1.localhost
                    - test2.localhost

    other:
        image: php:7.2.7
        container_name: other
        tty: true
        networks:
            - default

networks:
    default:
```

## Using Docker Network links

Second solution uses [docker network links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links). This works the other way around. For each dependend container (other) you can specify additional links / names that should be forwarded to the webserver.

`docker-compose-yml`:
    version: "3.1"

```
services:

    webserver:
        build: webserver
        container_name: web
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - ./webserver/html/:/application
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    other:
        image: php:7.2.7
        container_name: other
        tty: true
        links:
            - "webserver:test1.localhost"
            - "webserver:test2.localhost"
```

Comment: Using "links:" is deprecated!
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#links

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand.
You can resolve by containername between containers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Problem is that I want to resolve multiple names to the same container. In the example: `test1.localhost` and `test2.localhost` to container `web`.

Comment: try to change your hosts file to:
127.0.0.1   test1.localhost test2.localhost localhost

Comment: AFAIK you cannot "forward" names in that way. Also even if I could what is `test2.localhost localhost` to mean?